# How to change a string variable inside a lambda expression?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am working in cocos2dx and I am trying to change the value of a string variable called chosenBlockTexture inside of a lambda expression that acts as a callback to a button press. Unfortunately, I cannot find a fix to this, it keeps telling me that I have unhandled exceptions at a specific memory location.

The variable chosenBlockTexture is declared outside of this for loop, and the loop iterates through a dictionary to automatically generate buttons that would let me change the value of the chosenBlockTexture variable.

```
for (auto it : blockDict) {
    auto newBlockButton = Button::create("button-block-basic.png", "button-block-basic.png", button-block-basic.png");
    auto buttonImage = Sprite::create(it.first);

    newBlockButton->setPosition(Vec2(76 * blockDictIter, 64));
    buttonImage->setPosition(Vec2(76 * blockDictIter, 64));
    buttonImage->setGlobalZOrder(2);
    buttonImage->setScale(0.75);

    newBlockButton->addTouchEventListener([&](Ref* sender, Widget::TouchEventType type) {
        switch (type)
        {
        case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::BEGAN:
            break;
        case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::ENDED:
            chosenBlockTexture = it.first
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
     });

    blockDictIter++;

    newBlockButton->setGlobalZOrder(1);
    this->addChild(newBlockButton);
    this->addChild(buttonImage);
}
```

[This is the error I keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVVkb.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the variable chosenBlockTexture is a methode variable the compiler wil not find the error  :

```
std::string chosenBlockTexture = "123";
Button* playButton = Button::create("butplay.png",
                                   "butplay_in.png"
                                    );
playButton->setPosition(Vec2(58.0f, 32.0f));
playButton->addTouchEventListener([&](Ref* sender, Widget::TouchEventType type) {
    switch (type)
    {
    case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::BEGAN:
        break;
    case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::ENDED:
            chosenBlockTexture = "pipo";
            CCLOG("chosenBlockTexture = %s", chosenBlockTexture.c_str());
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
 });
```

The output is:
chosenBlockTexture = ~\336

The above example compiles, but CCLOG is not giving the result string "pipo".

When the button is pushed, the var is out of scope, and it wil give unpredicted result (i used xcode iOS).

If i make chosenBlockTexture a private variable (make the variable an private var, and remove it form the methode), its working oke and the output is "chosenBlockTexture = pipo".

```
 private:
    std::string chosenBlockTexture = "123";
};
```